# I need to put some text after scoreboard value on sign

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to put 'seconds' after the scoreboard value, but it appears on the next line or there is no text at all.
Command:

```
/data merge block ~ ~3 ~ {front_text:{messages:['["",{"text":"Untill detonation:","color":"red"}]','{"score":{"name":"NukeTimer","objective":"SCPTimers"},"color":"red"}','["",{"text":"секунд","color":"red"}]','["",{"text":"","color":"red"}]','[" "]']}}
```

What I need to do?

I am playing Java Edition 1.20.

Answer (score 1):

Lets format that data so it's a little easier to read:

```
{
    front_text: {
        messages: [
            '["",{"text":"Untill detonation:","color":"red"}]',
            '{"score":{"name":"NukeTimer","objective":"SCPTimers"},"color":"red"}',
            '["",{"text":"секунд","color":"red"}]',
            '["",{"text":"","color":"red"}]',
            '[" "]'
        ]
    }
}
```

You've got five lines of text there, and signs only display four lines of text, so the last one is going to be cut off.

To get the "Until detonation:" and score to display on the same line, you need to put them in the same text object. Take the score object from line 2:

```
{"score":{"name":"NukeTimer","objective":"SCPTimers"},"color":"red"}
```

and insert it into the list of text objects on the first line:

```
["",{"text":"Untill detonation:","color":"red"}]
```

like so:

```
["",{"text":"Untill detonation:","color":"red"},{"score":{"name":"NukeTimer","objective":"SCPTimers"},"color":"red"}]
```

Full command:

```
/data merge block ~ ~3 ~ {front_text:{messages:['["",{"text":"Untill detonation:","color":"red"},{"score":{"name":"NukeTimer","objective":"SCPTimers"},"color":"red"}]','["",{"text":"секунд","color":"red"}]','["",{"text":"","color":"red"}]','[" "]']}}
```

For more information on how JSON text is formatted, [the wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format) gives an in-depth explanation.

Comment: I needed something like that:
Until detonation:
X seconds

where X is the scoreboard value (so Until detonation is on the 1 line, and X seconds - on the second.)